# Integration (or emulation) of Vim with NetBeans or Eclipse

Tags: ide, plugin-eclim, vrapper

**Notice**:
I hope this question fits our site, I'm open to any comments.

---

I've been a Vim user for 15 years now, always as an editor on its own, with some IDE functionalities such as autocompletion among others.

Right now at work I've had to use NetBeans, and I installed [jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/). It works pretty well, provided you've enabled some settings<sup>[1]</sup>, with only a few missing features like plugins.

Is there any review or experience regarding the integration of Vim with NetBeans in comparison with the integration of Vim with Eclipse (whose only plugin I know of is [Vrapper](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vrapper-vim))?

What I want to know is: should I consider Eclipse as an alternative to NetBeans regarding only its integration with respect to Vim?

---

<sup>[1]: The most important setting is enabling (both on Linux [what I use] or Mac): "Mac Retina Cursor Xor Bug".</sup>

Comment: Have you checked out `:nbstart` and `:help netbeans` for Vim's existing netbeans integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had great luck recently with [Eclim](http://eclim.org/), an Eclipse plugin that gives you vim windows. I sometimes find myself still just using Vim by itself, but it does give you the best of both worlds, sort of. I've never used Vrapper, but I imagine it would also work well.

It's possible an Eclipse environment might require additional setup on the vim side; mine certainly did. Once the IDE is able to load a vim window, it's a matter of getting rid of any strange behavior the new environment creates, such as additional ENTER prompts. I had to fix a couple such annoyances but it works great now.

So yes, you should definitely consider Eclipse an alternative to NetBeans for vim integration. At least give it a try, and if you don't like it, then no harm done.

Comment: To expand on the description of Eclim, it enables Eclipse and Vim to talk with each other, it's *not* a mere partial key remapping as many IDE's Vi plugins or modes are. Eclim lets you use the full power of Vim within Eclipse and to access many features of Eclipse from within Vim.